# How to apply a transition speed to a scaled image on hover?

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transitions, css-transforms

I have a card in the snippet below. I'm trying to figure out how to apply a transition speed to the scaled image on hover. What I've tried isn't working.

I have an arrow icon at the base of the card with a transition speed applied. It is working fine. I've set the speed of the icon different so you can see the difference.

**How do I apply a transition speed to the photo image being scaled on hover?** (not the icon)

```css
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: normal;
}

a {
  color: #005fec;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  line-height: 1.75rem;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  h4 {
    font-size: 1.75rem;
    line-height: 2.25rem;
  }
}
h4 + img {
  margin-top: 3rem;
}

h6 {
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
}

.kicker {
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  line-height: 0.75rem;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.kicker--bold, .kicker--bold {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.img-fluid {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.next__cards {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .next__cards {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
}
.next__card {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0px 12px 24px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 0 1.5rem 2rem;
}
.next__card--link {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  width: 1.5rem;
}
.next__card--link-spacer {
  transition: all 2s ease;
}
.next__card--link:hover .next__card--link-spacer {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.next__card--link ::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  content: "";
}
@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .next__card {
    margin-left: 0.75rem;
    margin-right: 0.75rem;
  }
}
.next__card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 12px rgba(25, 30, 36, 0.08);
}
.next__card img {
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  transition: transform .2s;
}
.next__card:hover img.next__card-img {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .next__card {
    max-width: 50%;
  }
}
.next__card-content {
  padding: 2.5rem;
}
.next__card-title {
  margin: 1.5rem auto 2rem;
}
.next__card .kicker, .next__card-title {
  padding: 0;
}
.next__card:hover .next__card-title {
  color: #005fec;
}
.next__card-footer {
  width: 100%;
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .next__card {
    max-width: 376px;
  }
  .next__card:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .next__card:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="next__cards">
  <div class="next__card">
    <img class="img-fluid next__card-img" src="https://www.nextiva.com/assets/jpg/case-study/xCase-Studies-Jersey-College-card.jpg.pagespeed.ic.Ai7henX86J.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="next__card-content">
      <h6 class="kicker kicker--bold">customer story</h6>
      <h4 class="next__card-title">
        See how EagleRider switched phone providers easily
      </h4>
      <div class="next__card-footer">
        <a class="next__card--link" target="_blank" href="#">
          <span class="next__card--link-spacer"></span>
          <img src="https://www.nextiva.com/assets/svg/arrow-right.svg" alt="right arrow">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have changed the hover from `0.2s` to `0.1s` and worked to me.

Comment: This wasn't about the icon. It's about the image at the top of the card. I've applied a transition to that as well and it's not functioning as expected.

Comment: The question is in regards to the image being scaled. The icon is not being scaled, only the photographic image is being scaled.

Comment: The transition on the img seems to work to me, it's just set at a fifth of a second so doesn't take long. Can you describe a bit more what you want it to look like when transitioning?

Comment: Try applying a 3s timing to it. It doesn't work.

Comment: It works fine for me, I tried 3s as you suggested and also 20s just to make sure. How are you selecting it?

Comment: I am now wondering whether you actually want not just the image to expand within the containing div (which it is doing fine) but whether you want it to show the whole image scaled, not cropped/constrained within its parent?

Comment: I've updated  my answer with a second snippet which allows the image to grow outside of its parent.

Answer (score 1):

Altering the transition on the img does work. But of course we need to make sure we pick the right image.

The scaleable img can be selected and the transition altered in this styling:

```
.next__card img {
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  transition: transform 3s; /* changed from .2s */
}
```

Here's the altered snippet that does that:

```css
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: normal;
}

a {
  color: #005fec;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  line-height: 1.75rem;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  h4 {
    font-size: 1.75rem;
    line-height: 2.25rem;
  }
}

h4+img {
  margin-top: 3rem;
}

h6 {
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
}

.kicker {
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  line-height: 0.75rem;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.kicker--bold,
.kicker--bold {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.img-fluid {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.next__cards {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .next__cards {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
}

.next__card {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0px 12px 24px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 0 1.5rem 2rem;
}

.next__card--link {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  width: 1.5rem;
}

.next__card--link-spacer {
  transition: all 2s ease;
}

.next__card--link:hover .next__card--link-spacer {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.next__card--link ::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  content: "";
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .next__card {
    margin-left: 0.75rem;
    margin-right: 0.75rem;
  }
}

.next__card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 12px rgba(25, 30, 36, 0.08);
}

.next__card img {
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  transition: transform 3s;
  /* changed from .2s */
}

.next__card:hover img.next__card-img {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .next__card {
    max-width: 50%;
  }
}

.next__card-content {
  padding: 2.5rem;
}

.next__card-title {
  margin: 1.5rem auto 2rem;
}

.next__card .kicker,
.next__card-title {
  padding: 0;
}

.next__card:hover .next__card-title {
  color: #005fec;
}

.next__card-footer {
  width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .next__card {
    max-width: 376px;
  }
  .next__card:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .next__card:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="next__cards">
  <div class="next__card">
    <img class="img-fluid next__card-img" src="https://www.nextiva.com/assets/jpg/case-study/xCase-Studies-Jersey-College-card.jpg.pagespeed.ic.Ai7henX86J.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="next__card-content">
      <h6 class="kicker kicker--bold">customer story</h6>
      <h4 class="next__card-title">
        See how EagleRider switched phone providers easily
      </h4>
      <div class="next__card-footer">
        <a class="next__card--link" target="_blank" href="#">
          <span class="next__card--link-spacer"></span>
          <img src="https://www.nextiva.com/assets/svg/arrow-right.svg" alt="right arrow">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

UPDATE: If it is required that the img not only scales but also 'breaks out' of its parent, so that it can all be seen without cropping then make the parent have overflow visible.

Here is the altered snippet:

```css
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: normal;
}

a {
  color: #005fec;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  line-height: 1.75rem;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  h4 {
    font-size: 1.75rem;
    line-height: 2.25rem;
  }
}

h4+img {
  margin-top: 3rem;
}

h6 {
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
}

.kicker {
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  line-height: 0.75rem;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.kicker--bold,
.kicker--bold {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.img-fluid {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.next__cards {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .next__cards {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
}

.next__card {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0px 12px 24px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 0 1.5rem 2rem;
}

.next__card--link {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  width: 1.5rem;
}

.next__card--link-spacer {
  transition: all 2s ease;
}

.next__card--link:hover .next__card--link-spacer {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.next__card--link ::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  content: "";
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .next__card {
    margin-left: 0.75rem;
    margin-right: 0.75rem;
  }
}

.next__card {
  overflow: visible;
}

.next__card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 12px rgba(25, 30, 36, 0.08);
}

.next__card img {
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  transition: transform 3s;
  /* changed from .2s */
}

.next__card:hover img.next__card-img {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .next__card {
    max-width: 50%;
  }
}

.next__card-content {
  padding: 2.5rem;
}

.next__card-title {
  margin: 1.5rem auto 2rem;
}

.next__card .kicker,
.next__card-title {
  padding: 0;
}

.next__card:hover .next__card-title {
  color: #005fec;
}

.next__card-footer {
  width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .next__card {
    max-width: 376px;
  }
  .next__card:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .next__card:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="next__cards">
  <div class="next__card">
    <img class="img-fluid next__card-img" src="https://www.nextiva.com/assets/jpg/case-study/xCase-Studies-Jersey-College-card.jpg.pagespeed.ic.Ai7henX86J.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="next__card-content">
      <h6 class="kicker kicker--bold">customer story</h6>
      <h4 class="next__card-title">
        See how EagleRider switched phone providers easily
      </h4>
      <div class="next__card-footer">
        <a class="next__card--link" target="_blank" href="#">
          <span class="next__card--link-spacer"></span>
          <img src="https://www.nextiva.com/assets/svg/arrow-right.svg" alt="right arrow">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```